# how to fill the empty space with ListView after hiding a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-button

I have a simple vertical `LinearLayout` in which there is a `button` on the top and a `Listview` below it. 
What I want is that when the `button` is pressed, it hides (using *View.GONE*) and the empty space generated by it is filled by `ListView`. 
But after all the efforts, I have not been able to implement it.

I tried `invalidate()` and `onDraw()`, I tried giving `layout_weight=1` to the `ListView`, I tried `forceLayout()`, `requestLayout()` methods as well but none of them worked.

The strange thing is that if there is `EditText` or `TextView` or any other component instead of `ListView`, its working fine i.e. `Edittext` etc. go and grab the empty space generated by hiding the `Button`. But in case of `ListView` , its not happening.

Comment: @user370305 : then how come the EditText etc. go and fill that space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thing is perfectly working in my emulator

```
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new ProgressTask().execute();
            btn1.setVisibility(8);
        }
    })
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/itemlist"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is there a ListView below the button you are hiding? And btw what is "8" here?

Comment: I am trying. Anyways thanx for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

check this......

```
     public class TestingActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button checkBtn;
     String[] temp={"item 1","item 2","item 3"};
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getListView().setAdapter(new  ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, temp));
      checkBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

      checkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {

       public void onClick(View v)
       {


         checkBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);


       }});

     } }
```

xml is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="check connetion" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollingCache="false" >
</ListView>

  </LinearLayout>
```